# How to use LINQ to get unique columns from a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` in C# with columns defined as follows:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("OrgName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("OrgExId", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("UserExId", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("UserEmail", typeof(string));
```

"UserName", "UserExId", and "UserEmail" are all unique and they are grouped by "OrgName" and "OrgExId"

I want to write a LINQ query to make a new `DataTable` that contains unique "OrgExId's" and "OrgName's"

This is as far as I got:

```
var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row["OrgExId"] into orgs
              select orgs;
```

Specifically in this query, I don't understand how I am supposed to select the rows from the original `DataTable`. Visual Studio says orgs is of the type `IGrouping, but I have never really seen this type before and am not sure how to manipulate it.

Is this a key value pair?

Sorry about that all. I did not specify my end result.

I want to end up with a `DataTable` with two columns, distinct "OrgExId" and "OrgName". (There is a one to one relationship between "OrgExId" and "OrgName")

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: Heh... you've got 3 different answers but no-one knows what you need out of your query.  :)

Comment: @Kevin, Sorry about that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Do you mean you want to end up with a `DataTable` with two columns?

Comment: yes two columns sorry long day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need is a Distinct clause

```
    var output = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new {OrgExId = x["OrgExId"], OrgName = x["OrgName"]})
        .Distinct();
```

You can then iterate over this and build a `DataTable` or whatever you need.

**UPDATE:** You asked for the output to be a DataTable and the above solution didn't quite sit well with me since it requires extra work.  To make this more efficient you could do a custom equality comparer.

Your linq looks like this...

```
    // This returns a DataTable
    var output = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Distinct(new OrgExIdEqualityComparer())
        .CopyToDataTable();
```

And your comparer looks like this...

```
public class OrgExIdEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        return x["OrgExId"].Equals(y["OrgExId"]);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return obj["OrgExId"].GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Key` property of `IGrouping`:

```
var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by new {
                  row.GetField<string>("OrgExId"),
                  row.GetField<string>("UserName")
              } into orgs
              select orgs.Key;
```

It will give you collection of anonymous types. To get `DataTable` you can simply [iterate over results and add it into `DataTable`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6d4e2579-f4b5-497c-ad00-7c347eb1f902/converting-anonymous-type-generated-by-linq-to-a-datatable-type?forum=csharplanguage).

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("OrgName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("OrgExId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("UserExId", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("UserEmail", typeof(string));

    // put some data for testing purpose

    var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(id, i.ToString(), "user_name", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    var x = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.Field<string>("UserName")).Distinct();

    Console.WriteLine(x);
```